# latest Firestore update throws symbol not found arm64 error for InvitesReceiverInternal::CreateInstance

Tags: ios, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

After installing FirebaseFirestore 0.11.0 (was 0.9.2), xcode (V9.3 9E145) throws the following error:

> Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
>   "firebase::invites::internal::InvitesReceiverInternalIos::InvitesReceiverInternalIos(firebase::App
>   const&)", referenced from:
>         firebase::invites::internal::InvitesReceiverInternal::CreateInstance(firebase::App
>   const&, firebase::invites::internal::ReceiverInterface*) in
>   FirebaseFirestore(invites_receiver_internal_e5eabc576d1cdac1852bb0ac192cac41.o)
>   ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64 clang: error: linker
>   command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Could it be a new framework requirement? 
I know invites require the addressBook framework, but maybe a new framework is required?

**Note:** i am not using Firebase Invites, somehow it's complaining about invite methods missing in the Firebase Core...

I've cleaned the project, i've updated all the firebase pods to the latest version too, no luck.

Any help is much appreciated!